# Linux Mint starting into Emergency Mode

Tags: linux, startup, troubleshooting

I run Linux mint of an external hard drive. Today it made I funny noise and when I rebooted it entered emergency mode. I can still use my laptop via:

- Advanced options for Linux mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit
- ...(recovery mode)
- fsck - check all file systems
- resume - resume normal boot

This has happened to me before and after using it in recovery mode for about two weeks (probably not the best) it somehow fixed itself. It seems to enter emergency mode half way through a file check. How do I fix this and get it running as normal?

**More Info**

I have tried the method given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem) which did not work.

The error message coming up is:

> [ 2.218981] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on  pch transcoder A
>
> [ 2.2189009] [drm:inten_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcorder A FIFO underrun
>
> Welcome to emergency mode!...